# How to lowercase first letter of Textmate snippet input?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I have shortcut for creating getter method and here is my snippet code right now:

```
public function get${1:PropertyName}() {
    return \$this->${1:propertyName};
}
$0
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
public function getAreaCode() {
    return $this->areaCode;
}
```

So the question is, how to automatically transform input's first letter into lowercase, but only on the second line?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regexp match that matches the first character and modifies it like this:

```
public function get${1/./\u/}() {
    return \$this->${1:propertyName};
}
$0
```

I've used this, to also add the property and setting the scope with dropdown:

```
${2|private,protected,public|} \$${1};

${3|public,protected,private|} function get${1/./\u$0/}() {
    return \$this->${1:propertyName};
}
${3} function set${1/./\u$0/}(\$value) {
    \$this->${1} = \$value;
    return \$this;
}
$0
```

[image: Final result]

See *Transformation* section on [Macromates](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/the-power-of-snippets/) for more.